# Why DataGrip's DDL Mapping Sync routines not completely?

Tags: jetbrains-ide, datagrip

[image: Dump Database to DDL Data Source]

[image: There's 882 routines remote but only 103 syned to local DDL mapping]

There's 882 routines remote but only 103 syned to local DDL mapping,
even I tried dump again.

Why I could not dump all routines ?

Comment: Seems to be a bug. Is it possible to reproduce that in a sample database and share the database dump? You can create bug request at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=DBE

Comment: I can't see any tables in your DDL data source too, is there any errors?